# Build of reactNative app fails on IOS using CLI and xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I tried to build a simple reactNative app for ios using CLI and xcode.
Both builds fails with a different error.
Prior to both builds, I ran the following

```
npm install
pod install
```

1. Build using CLI
   The steps are:

   npx react-native run-ios

Having done so I found some errors on the log file which I am attaching

```
    manish.basdeo@AMAC02SNHPHFVH3 Top100 % npx react-native run-ios
info Found Xcode workspace "Top100.xcworkspace"

info Launching iPhone 11 (iOS 13.3)
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace Top100.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Top100 -destination id=37E2E23C-60E2-42D4-8053-525A907ED979")
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Top100.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Build settings from command line:
    TOOLCHAINS = com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault

Prepare build
note: Using legacy build system
    
    
    <unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/manish.basdeo/Desktop/Top100/Top100/ios/Pods/@/Users/manish.basdeo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Top100-etyxtwwnmplrdtdxgkmuhxstoudh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Top100.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Top100.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Top100.SwiftFileList'
    Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
    ** BUILD FAILED **
    
    
    The following build commands failed:
        CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    (1 failure)
```

[image]
2) Build using XCODE

[image]

[image]

How can I fix both errors?

Comment: What version is your Xcode?

Comment: The xcode version is 11.3.1

Comment: Upgrading to the latest Xcode should resolve your issues. Can you try that and let me know if it resolves it?